# How to get all the combinations of a list of pairs with a restriction on indices

Tags: python, combinations

I have originally two lists of numbers, but for this case, let's say I have a list of tuples and I would like to get all the possible combinations such that the output has a member of the first pair in index 0, one of the second pair in index 1, etc.

For example, let the list be: `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5,6)]`

And I want to get:

```
1, 3, 5
1, 3, 6
1, 4, 5
1, 4, 6
2, 3, 5
2, 3, 6
2, 4, 5
2, 4, 6
```

The list can be of any length. I tried using `itertools.permutations` over the two original lists like this:
`[list(zip(permutation, list2)) for permutation in itertools.permutations(list1, len(list2))]`

but it would return all the possible permutations which is not what I need.

Comment: Seems you have missed `itertools.product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a vanilla breadth-first search/depth-first search:

```py
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5,6)]

def search(points):
    points = list(points)
    paths = []
    if points:
        first_points = points.pop(0)
    else:
        return [[]]
    for point in first_points:
        for path in bfs(points):
            paths.append([point] + path)
    
    return paths

print(search(a))
```

Returns:

```
[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Now, I wrote this hastily and it's not the most efficient code, but it'll do the job